# change first letter of a word in python with all the letters in the alphabet and generate a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a string say 
`string = 'bcde'`

What I want to do is replace the first letter from the `string` (i.e. `b`) and replace it doing iterations for each letter in the alphabet, till z.

Desired Output:

```
['acde', 'bcde', 'ccde', 'dcde', 'ecde', 'fcde', ..., 'zcde']
```

This is the code that I'm currently using, but I get the wrong output:

```
a = 'bcde'
a = list(a)
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabet = list(alphabet)
final = []
for n,i in enumerate(a):
    if i==b:
        a[i] = [alphabet[x] for x in alphabet ]
        final.append(a[i])
```

Comment: You don't want to iterate through `a` since you only want to change the first letter of `a`. You could instead iterate through the alphabet and, in the simplest approach, concatenate the letter to `a[1:]`.

Comment: love it or hate it here it is in one line `map(lambda x:x[0]+x[1],zip(alphabet,itertools.cycle((s[1:],)) ))`

Comment: @themistoklik `itertools.repeat(s[1:])` is more succinct than `itertools.cycle((s[1:],))`. And in Python 3 you need to wrap that `map` call in `list()`.

Answer (score 4):

It could be done really easily with list comprehension

```
a = 'bcde'
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
post_string = a[1:]
final = [letter+post_string for letter in alphabet]
```

Comment: You don't need to turn `alphabet` into a list. You can iterate over strings. And you can just do `import string` and then it's `... for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]`

Comment: You are right but I don't think he really wants the alphabet list really be the alphabet, it could be another kind of element in the list.

Comment: Or simply `[x+a[1:] for x in map(chr,range(97,123))]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Well, yes, that works, but I think using a literal string is simpler (and much more efficient) than constructing a map object from scratch. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right of course, but these constructs are good to be aware of, I actually prefer `[chr(x)+a[1:] for x in range(97,123)]` ;)

Answer (score 2):

this is all you need:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

a='bcde'
new_list = []
for i in alphabet:
    new_list.append(i+a[1:])
```

Comment: so what's the need to create a list?..for loop is used

Comment: Because that was the intention of the OP. And `print` is fundamentally different to creating a list. One is a data structure.

Comment: oh yeah..didn't see that..I have fixed now...pushing elements in the list instead of printing. this works....right?

Comment: It pays to read program specs carefully, otherwise you can end up creating code that works perfectly but doesn't do what's actually wanted. That's a good way to attract downvotes on SO, and a good way to get people mad at you if you're employed as a coder. :)

Comment: yeah..thanks for that..this was my first answer on SO! :)

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions here are way too complicated / over the top, just use a simple list comprehension:

```
text = 'abcd'
final = [c + text[1:] for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstvuwxyz']
```

If you need to use the alphabet multiple times, use `import string` and then `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 1):

Because one can always mispell alphabet :

```
s = 'bcde'
final = list(map(lambda x: chr(x + ord('a')) + s[1:], range(26)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
s = 'bcde'
final = []
if s[0] == 'b':
    final = ['{}{}'.format(i, s[1:]) for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
print(final)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> final
['acde', 'bcde', 'ccde', 'dcde', 'ecde', 'fcde', 'gcde', 'hcde', 'icde', 'jcde', 'kcde', 'lcde', 'mcde', 'ncde', 'ocde', 'pcde', 'qcde', 'rcde', 'scde', 'tcde', 'ucde', 'vcde', 'wcde', 'xcde', 'ycde', 'zcde']
```